# Dynamic LINQ Query in LINQ to Entities , problem with WHERE clause

Tags: asp.net, linq, dynamic

For the life of me, I can't figure out what the problem is with this:

```
tempData= from a in dx.SomeTable select a;

string searchField="ItemName";
string searchString="BoxPkg";

object[] parameters=new object[]{searchField,searchString};
tempData = tempData.Where("@0 like @1", parameters);
```

I get this error " {"Expression of type 'Boolean' expected"} "

Comment: Does it need to be `tempdata.Where("@0.Contains(@1)");` ?

Comment: Runtime error. BTW .Contains seems not to give any runtime error but it is not giving me the right results. I have a row with which has "Dent" as part of the value of the string that I search.But when I run this query, its not showing that record.

Comment: Any more suggestions ? I am kinda sitting on this issue for 2 days now :|

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're able to specify the property name (`ItemName`) as a parameter (`@0`). Try this instead:

```
tempData= from a in dx.SomeTable select a;

string searchField="ItemName";
string searchString="BoxPkg";

object[] parameters=new object[]{searchString};
tempData = tempData.Where(searchField + " like @0", parameters);
```